# Use double integrals to find the volume of the solid obtained by the rotation of the region

Tags: integration

I am unsure how to set up the integrals. The integration should be done in polar coordinates.

Here is what is give:

$D = \{ (x,y,z) | x^2 \le z \le 6 - x, 0\le x \le 2, y = 0\}$

in the xz-plane
about the z-axis.

Comment: You forgot to say what the axis of the rotation is...

Comment: you can make your life easier by using the theorems of Pappus: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html (need to do only a double integral).

Comment: Just did. Sorry.

Comment: The 'polar coordinate system' is a name for a [planar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system); in 3D space there are two commonly used system which can be considered 'polar': [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) and [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system). And I suppose you mean the cylindrical coordinate system...

Comment: Yeah. So what would the intergral look like?

Comment: :(. Please help me